# $V=M_n(\mathbb{R})$ is an inner product,$ \langle A,B\rangle=tr(B^tA).$ $T(A)=P^{-1}AP, P\in V $ Find $T^*$

Tags: linear-algebra

$V=M_n(\mathbb{R})$ is an inner product,$ \langle A,B\rangle=tr(B^tA).$

$T(A)=P^{-1}AP, P\in V $

Find $T^*$

$tr(B^tP^{-1}AP)=\langle P^{-1}AP,B\rangle = \langle T(A),B\rangle = \langle A,T^*(B)\rangle = tr((T^*(B))^tA \implies tr(B^tP^{-1}AP) = tr((T^*(B))^tA)$

Here I get stuck.

How can I find $T^*(B)$ ?, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trace is cyclic. So you can rewrite your last equality as
$$
\text{tr} (PB^{\text{t}}P^{-1} A) = \text{tr}((T^{\ast}(B))^{\text{t}}A)
$$
That gives you
\begin{align*}
PB^{\text{t}}P^{-1} &= (T^{\ast}(B))^{\text{t}} \\
(P^{-1})^{\text{t}}BP^{\text{t}}  &= T^\ast(B)
\end{align*}